# Treating \[...] nicely in Wolfram mode

Tags: syntax-table

In the Wolfram language, special characters such as ∂, ∫ and ζ can be displayed nicely in Mathematica and in the source, appear as `\[PartialD]`, `\[Integral]` and `\[Zeta]`.  In [`wolfram mode`](https://github.com/kawabata/wolfram-mode), the special characters are supported through font locking, but otherwise the syntax table does not account for them which is the cause of some bugs since `]` is marked as a delimiter (and was [reported](https://github.com/kawabata/wolfram-mode/issues/4) a while ago).

I wanted to create a pull-request to amend the syntax-table so that `\[` and `]` are matched delimiters; however, it seems like the syntax table can only allow a single character at a time to be defined, and multiple character sequences are only possible for comments.  So is it possible have `\[` and `]` be matched delimiters?

I also tried looking for a way to tell emacs to treat `\[...]` as a single "unit" so that the `]` at the end doesn't cause new issues; but to be honest I don't really know how to do that.

PS:  As far as I know, the elided text inside `\[...]` always consists of the set `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Comment: Not sure how this would affect delimiter matching, but what about using [prettify-symbols-mode](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/prog-mode.el?id=emacs-24.5#n57)? ([Quick intro](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/08/25/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-prettify-symbols-mode/))